# Error: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 1)

Tags: python, valueerror

```
filename = 'hw_25000.csv'

with open(filename, 'r') as infile:
    data = infile.read().split('\n')

    heights = []
    weights = []
    column = []

for row in data [1:] :
    index, height, weight = row.split(',') 

    height = float(height)
    weight = float(weight)
    index = float (index)
```

Comment: One of your rows did not contains any commas.  In fact, if the the last line of the file ends in a newline, then the last "row" will be the empty string.  That might be the problem.

Comment: Ohh thanks good sir its working now. im really grateful :>